# '90s Christian sci-fi book where the special police have mechanical gauntlets that let them fly and shoot

Tags: story-identification, novel, christian

Trying to find an '80s/'90s sci-fi book where the special police have mechanical gloves; gauntlets that let them fly and shoot and do everything. Christians are in secret and use a stone as a Bible- it resonates through the skeleton. Someone gets arrested for standing on a logo. An AI runs the world. There's a human breeding program. The gauntlet runs on chocolate if it needs too. I thought it was called *Xanan*.

Comment: Also asked at https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/enrrz3/a_christian_scifi_teen_book_i_thought_it_was/, although no answer was found, and it looks like the author deleted their account. No new details.

Comment: What does "The gauntlet runs on chocolate" mean? Were the mechanical gauntlets used by the police powered by using chocolate as a fuel? That seems a little unlikely.

Comment: No- that's what I mean. They had their own fuel but in a pinch they would absorb the energy in food.